# How to change the CSS font of user's input in SenseDateRangePicker extension

Tags: css

I am using the [SenseDateRangePicker](https://github.com/NOD507/SenseDateRangePicker) extension and I was asked to change the size of the input that gives each time for the user to select. I changed the font of almost everything in the CSS file of this extension but I can't find the styling that corresponds to the input. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: Thanks for posting. There are many extensions and plugins that goes by the name "Daterangepicker" so it would be helpful if you can mention the exact one you are referring to and can you also provide any code related to it that you have tried so far as without it more people won't be able to give you helpful advice on what to do next.

Comment: the extension is the SenseDateRangePicker.

Comment: Is it this input https://imgur.com/a/w624P8W ?

Comment: i can't find in the script the part which refers to the default text. Check here: https://imgur.com/Rpc967h. All I want is to change the size of the font because it is small on the screen.